# Mawk - removing special characters

Tags: awk

I use mawk.

I have a file:

```
{1: [u'Bank Pocztowy'], 2: [u'Pekao']}
```

I want to get the result:

```
{1: [uBank Pocztowy], 2: [uPekao]}
```

I tried this:

```
mawk '{gsub("\'",""); print}' file
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
$ mawk '{gsub("\'",""); print}' file
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gsub should be as below:

```
gsub(/\047/,"" )
```

chekc with

```
mawk '{gsub(/\047/,""); print}' file
```

I dont have mawk installed here. i only have nawk:

tested with nawk:

```
> echo "{1: [u'Bank Pocztowy'], 2: [u'Pekao']}" | nawk '{gsub(/\047/,"" ) ; print}'
{1: [uBank Pocztowy], 2: [uPekao]}
```

Alternatively ,If you want the solution in perl :

```
> echo "{1: [u'Bank Pocztowy'], 2: [u'Pekao']}" | perl -pe "s/\'//g"
{1: [uBank Pocztowy], 2: [uPekao]}
```

Comment: sarathi, This is a good solution. Thank you.--> " mawk '{gsub(/\047/,""); print}' file

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE #2 : realized I could clean it up even more so

```
[gnm]awk 'gsub("\47",_)~_'
```

If you really insists on using `traditional/linting` flag on `gawk`, i.e. `gawk -te` or `gawk -ce`, then do :

```
gawk -t NF=NF FS="'" OFS=''

   or even

gawk -c 1 RS="'" ORS=''
```

(UPDATE #1) EDIT : just realized it can be simplified to

```
[gnm]awk 'gsub(/\47+/,"")+!+""'
```

you can cut out the final print too, and make it go faster

```
 mawk/mawk2/gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "^$" } gsub(/[\047]+/, "") || 1'
```

Setting FS so not to spend time splitting fields. If single quotes exist, the gsub( ) return will handle the print automatically. The "or 1" is for the case when no single quotes exists that line.

Another method is use FS to detect the single quotes

```
 mawk/mawk2/gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\047" } (NF == 1) || gsub(/[\047]+/, "")'
```